# read a csv file and calculate the balance for a simple banking system in C

Tags: c, csv

I just started to learn C and I've been stuck here for a while. I know there are many similar problems posted but I can't find a solution to mine:(

So basically there's a file called "bankdata.csv", for example:

```
AC,2023,Jane Smith
TX,2023,2020-02-10,1023.34
AC,5023,Sally Long
TX,2023,2020-02,-103.34
TX,5023,2020-01-15,78.00
TX,5023,2020-03-29,22.00
```

you only need to look at the lines starting with "TX". The data represent type, account number, date, amount(positive for deposit, negative for withdraw),respectively.

What I wanna do is to write a function balance() which takes account num and file as inputs, calculate the balance for a specific account and output it as a float number.

Here's what I've tried:

```
float balance(char* num, FILE* file) {
    char line[1000];
    file = fopen ("bankdata.csv", "r");
    fgets (line, 1000, file);
    char *token = strtok (line, ","); // Extract the first token
    float bal = 0.00;

    while (token != NULL) {
        token = strtok (NULL, ","); //next token
        //printf (" %s\n", token);  
        if (strcmp (token, "TX") == 0) {
            char *acctnum = strtok (NULL, ",");
            if (strcmp (acctnum, num) == 0) {
                char *date = strtok (NULL, ",");
                char *amount = strtok (NULL, ",");
                float am = atof (amount);
                bal += am;
            }
        }

    }
    return bal;
}
```

Here I'm using a while loop to check each line in the file and extract "amount" for the line I want, to add them up. I realized I didn't deal with newlines. And also I got segmentation fault(core dumped). Could anyone help me fix this? Or is there a better way to approach?

So far I don't need it to be efficient, just hope it is as simple as possible! Thank you in advance!!

Comment: You need a loop around the `fgets()` call — `while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL) { … }`.  You extract the first token before you enter the loop you already have; you then extract the second token and check whether that is `TX` — it isn't.  There may be (probably are) other problems too.

Comment: Please do not use floating point numbers for money. Floating point numbers are inaccurate. People are funny over there money. Measure currency as integers and use pennies or the equilivant in the currency

Comment: @EdHeal So I should use double instead?

Comment: If you're dealing with real bank accounts, either use a `decimal` type (not yet standardized in C but they're a part of the current IEEE 754 standard and some FPU chips implement them — PowerPC for example) or use an integer type and multiply the 'dollars' (main currency unit) by 100 and add the fraction to that (so given "`3141.59`", calculate `3141 × 100 + 59`, noting that given "`2718.3`", you need to calculate `2718 × 100 + 30` (not just `3`).   Be cautious; people get upset if their bank loses them money.

Comment: I note that the CSV data is not wholly consistent.  In the entry `TX,2023,2020-02,-103.34`, the day of the month is missing from the date.

Comment: Best bet is use `long long`  and count in pennies. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0&t=7s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about the minimal set of changes that are probably acceptable for a classroom exercise — still totally ignoring error checking.

```
double balance(char* num, FILE* file)
{
    char line[1000];
    file = fopen("bankdata.csv", "r");             // Error checking!!!
    double bal = 0.00;

    while (fgets(line, 1000, file))
    {
        char *token = strtok(line, ",");           // Check not null
        if (strcmp(token, "TX") == 0)
        {
            char *acctnum = strtok(NULL, ",");     // Check not null
            if (strcmp(acctnum, num) == 0)
            {
                char *date = strtok(NULL, ",");    // Check not null
                char *amount = strtok(NULL, ",");  // Check not null
                double am = atof(amount);          // Check plausibility?
                bal += am;
                //printf("%s: %s: %9.2f %9.2f\n", acctnum, date, am, bal); 
            }
        }   
    }
    fclose(file);
    return bal;
}
```

If this were not a classroom exercise, using even `double` (instead of `float` as used in the question) is extremely dubious.  Money needs to be handled carefully.  For many purposes, storing a value as an integer is best.  For most currencies, there is some base unit (dollars, rupees, pounds, euros) and then two decimal places of some smaller unit (often cents).  For a value such as `3141.59`, you evaluate `3141 × 100 + 59` (noting that if you are given `2178.3`, you need to evaluate `2718 × 100 + 30` (not just `3`).  Some currencies have three decimal places for the smaller unit (Kuwaiti dinars have 1000 fils to the dinar).  Some currencies have no smaller unit; until replaced by the euro, the Italian lira was one such currency.  If it is available, then the modern [IEEE 754:2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) standard defines decimal floating types (`decimal32`, `decimal64` and `decimal128`); some hardware (notably IBM Power PC) provide support for this.  There is no standard C type for these decimal types yet, though.